# No folding of markdown files

Tags: neovim, folding, filetype-markdown

Running neovim 0.1.7.

When I open a markdown file, it does not fold - even when I try `zM` `zR` `zc`, etc.

`:set` tells me `ft=markdown` and `foldmethod=syntax`

How do I get the folding?

Answer (score 3):

The default Vim syntax file for [markdown](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/markdown.vim) does not define any regions that should be folded.

If you set foldmethod in your .vimrc to syntax, then that means, syntax based folding does not work for markdown. If a plugin did set it, you might want to check with the author of the plugin, why syntax based folding does not work for you. You can check, where this was last set by `:verbose :set foldmethod?`

Also, you might want to consider using the plugin [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown), as it does allow folding of markdown files, although it uses an expression-based folding method.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

You're more than welcome to steal snippets from my  [bat belt](https://github.com/ipatch/dotfiles) if you'd like

---

So I came across this same scenario a couple of days ago, and ended up watching this

Which lead me to putting the the following together,

`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown/folding.vim`

```
function! MarkdownFolds()
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
  if match(thisline, '^##') >= 0
    return ">2"
  elseif match(thisline, '^#') >= 0
    return ">1"
  else
    return "="
  endif
endfunction
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=MarkdownFolds()

function! MarkdownFoldText()
  let foldsize = (v:foldend-v:foldstart)
  return getline(v:foldstart).' ('.foldsize.' lines)'
endfunction
setlocal foldtext=MarkdownFoldText()
```

but still relied on using the default key bindings for folding

so long story short I mapped the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to toggle code folding with the below snippet in my `.vimrc`

```
" enable code folding
set foldmethod=syntax
" NOTE: the below settings remember code folds on a per file basis
" CREDIT:  https://github.com/d86leader/vim-config/blob/58b5ff43c268c74c5aa2e7f6e931167f6064c02f/vimrc#L412

augroup autoview
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave ?* call <SID>make_view()
  autocmd BufWinEnter ?* call <SID>load_view()
augroup END
fun! s:make_view() abort
  if @% != "" && &foldmethod != 'diff'
    mkview!
  endif
endfun
fun! s:load_view() abort
  if @% != ""
    silent! loadview
  endif
endfun
```

---

***Disclaimer***

Make sure you create the appropriate directories to store the view files, so when you close a file / buffer (n)vim remembers to restore your previous code fold settings.

cheers 
Chris