# Markdown folding in vim 8.2

Tags: folding, filetype-markdown

I'm using vim 8.2 on Win 10. I want to enable markdown folding with the built-in markdown.vim.

But it will not work. I have tried solutions from other questions (e.g., [Enable Expr Folding in Markdown](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20913/enable-expr-folding-in-markdown) and [How to fold markdown using the built-in markdown mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9543/how-to-fold-markdown-using-the-built-in-markdown-mode)), but to no avail.

My vimrc contains...

```
let g:markdown_folding = 1
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['vim', 'yaml', 'python', 'bash=sh', 'sql', 'git', 'make', 'html', 'css', 'javascript', 'js=javascript', 'json=javascript', 'xml']
syntax enable
set nocompatible
```

My file is detected as markdown, as shown here...

`:filetype` returns `detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON`
`:set ft` returns `markdown`
`:set foldmethod?` returns `manual`

`:scriptnames` output includes...

```
27: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\ftplugin\markdown.vim
30: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\syntax\markdown.vim
```

I do not have a `vimwiki` plugin (one user reported getting rid of vimwiki plugin solved the issue)

Yet `zc`, `zR`, `zM`, and `zo` all result in `E490: No fold found`, no matter where I place the cursor (on the `##`, on the heading name, or inside the text associated with that heading)

Hmmm...

I just found another question regarding this topic ([No folding of markdown files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13568/no-folding-of-markdown-files/13569#13569)) which contains what seems to be a solution, but which is a bit beyond my vim skill level. Does anyone recommend I try that solution? I'd rather not unless it truly is the only solution to my problem.

Further info per comments...

`:version` contains `+folding`
`:verbose set foldmethod?` returns `foldmethod=manual`

markdown.vim contains the following if-statement..

```
if has("folding") && exists("g:markdown_folding")
  setlocal foldexpr=MarkdownFold()
  setlocal foldmethod=expr
  setlocal foldtext=MarkdownFoldText()
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= " foldexpr< foldmethod< foldtext<"
endif
```

`has("folding")` is true
`exists("g:markdown_folding")` is **false**

**AHA!!!**

.. and the reason markdown_folding was false? ...a **typo** in my gvimrc (!)

I fixed the typo and folding is operational!

Comment: What does `:verbose set foldmethod?` say? Does `:version` say `+folding` (that folding support is included)? The `markdown.vim` ftplugin should [set `foldmethod=expr`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L69), I wonder why you're not seeing that...

Comment: I guess you could double check that your `ftplugin/markdown.vim` *actually* has those lines setting `foldmethod` etc... I don't see why it wouldn't... But you might as well want to look inside to make sure.

Comment: `verbose set foldmethod?` returns `foldmethod=manual`. `:version` has `+folding`. The `set foldmethod=expr` in markdown.vim is inside an if-statement with two conditions. I am checking those conditions and will update my original post accordingly

Comment: Problem solved. Details in my orig post. filbranden thanks for the questions. It would have taken me a lot longer to find my typo without them.

Comment: I guess you mean `exists("g:markdown_folding")` right? `has()` checks other things... Would you mind posting a self-answer to your question? (Otherwise we can close it as a problem that can't be reproduced...)

Comment: Also, always double-check foldenable (toggle with zi)

Comment: Yes I meant exists("g:markdown_folding"), not has("g:markdown_folding") !!! I pasted the if statement correctly but mistakenly wrote 'has' in the text below. Thanks for pointing that out. I am fixing it.

Comment: Sorry I was too late to do a self-answer, and the question has been closed. Is there a way to re-open and change it to a self-answer? I tried an edit, but didn't see how to get the self-answer option back.

Comment: @BinaryBob I just reopened the question, so go ahead and post an answer. Edit your question to make it accurate to what your problem was, if needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a typo in my .gvimrc.

```
"WRONG .gvimrc
let g:markdownfolding = 1
```

.. I had omitted the underscore between 'markdown' and 'folding'. I realized this when I manually evaluated the two clauses of this if statement from markdown.vim...

```
if has("folding") && exists("g:markdown_folding")
```

the exists() was returning false, which was a big clue and led me to look at my own gvimrc and notice the missing underscore. The corrected gvimrc line looks like...

```
"CORRECT .gvimrc
let g:markdown_folding = 1
```

Comment: Please tick your question as "answered"